# RESTful web services on JBoss WildFly 13 works from browser & curl but not from Unit tests - 404 error

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, resteasy, junit5

I have an Application deployed on JBoss WildFly 13.0.0.Final as an EAR running on EE8 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. All the methods work fine when called from the Applications web pages.

I can ping successfully 'My IP address', 127.0.0.1 & locahost:

> ping 192.999.9.255 PING 192.999.1.255
>   (192.999.9.255): 56 data bytes 64 bytes from 192.999.1.23: icmp_seq=0
>   ttl=64 time=0.067 ms 64 bytes from 192.999.1.23: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64
>   time=0.147 ms 64 bytes from 192.99.1.23: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.098
>   ms
>
> PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1:
>   icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1
>   ttl=64 time=0.085 ms 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64
>   time=0.076 ms
>
> PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1:
>   icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1
>   ttl=64 time=0.084 ms 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64
>   time=0.090 ms

My usr/hosts is standard:

> 127.0.0.1       localhost
>
> 255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
>
> ::1 localhost
>
> fe80::1%lo0     localhost

I can access one of the web services and display the JSON from curl:

```
MacBook-Pro:bin NOTiFY$ curl "http://localhost:8080/NOTiFYwell/notifywell/get-all-enumbers/"
[
  {
    "id": "5b6c5dbefac4f7105b3cca2e",
    "code": "E100",
    "name": "Curcumin (from turmeric)",
    "colour": "Yellow-orange",
    "status": "Approved in the EU.Approved in the US."
  },
```

and from the browser:

[image]

However when I run my JUnit 5 test:

```
    @Test
    public final void test01GetListEnumbers() throws IOException {
        System.out.println(">>>>> test01GetListEnumbers .....");

        String url = "http://localhost:8080/NOTiFYwell/notifywell/get-all-enumbers/";
        System.out.println(">>>>> test01GetListEnumbers url = " + url);

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        httpGet.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON);

        //Execute and get the response.
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        System.out.println(">>>>> test01GetListEnumbers response getStatus = " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        System.out.println(">>>>> test01GetListEnumbers response getEntity = " + EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

    }
```

I get:

test01GetListEnumbers ..... test01GetListEnumbers url = http://localhost:8080/NOTiFYwell/notifywell/get-all-enumbers/ test01GetListEnumbers response getStatus = 404 test01GetListEnumbers 
 response getEntity =

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /NOTiFYwell/notifywell/get-all-enumbers/. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><a 
href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT</a> 
<hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

In WireShark I see:

> 3027  26.303256   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   HTTP    275 GET
>   /NOTiFYwell/notifywell/get-all-enumbers/ HTTP/1.1
>
> 3028  26.303279   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 56  8080 → 50922 [ACK] Seq=1
>   Ack=220 Win=408064 Len=0 TSval=635600988 TSecr=635600988
>
> 3029  26.304989   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   HTTP    652 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 
>   (text/html)

All my JUnit test were working on my previous MacBook Pro (July 2018) with WildFly 12.0.0.Final on EE8 & macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. I have recently upgraded to WildFly 13.0.0.Final running on EE8. In both cases my series of Unit Tests accessing my web services used the Apache HTTP Core 4.4.10, Client 4.5.6 JARs.

Tried many of the SO suggestions to no avail.

Comment: It looks like you're using Jetty in tests not WildFly.

Answer (score 0):

[@James R. Perkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152794/james-r-perkins)
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I stopped Wildfly 13 and sure enough, I still had something listening on Port 8080

> MacBook-Pro:bin NOTiFY$ sudo lsof -i :8080 Password: COMMAND PID
>   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME java    437
>   NOTiFY  163u  IPv6 0x299d8c12df3e5311      0t0  TCP localhost:http-alt
>   (LISTEN)

Killed the PID and ran my JUnit test again and (as hoped) got:

> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,
>   localhost/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1] failed: Connection refused

Restarted WildFly 13 and successfully re-ran my JUnit test:

> test01GetListEnumbers url = http://localhost:8080/NOTiFYwell/notifywell/get-all-enumbers/
>   test01GetListEnumbers response getStatus = 200
>   test01GetListEnumbers response getEntity = [   {
>       "id": "5b6c5dbefac4f7105b3cca2e",
>       "code": "E100",
>       "name": "Curcumin (from turmeric)",
>       "colour": "Yellow-orange",
>       "status": "Approved in the EU.Approved in the US."   },

Still not sure where Jetty 9.x has come from.

This corresponds with having to reboot my Mac after I used 'Migration Assistant' to copy everything from my old MacBook to the new. Jetty appears to start on reboot. Will investigate.